# Variables: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm working on a support vector regression and I'm trying to split dataset in train and test. When I run my model I receive this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-c24eb12af231> in <module>
     20 
     21 # Identify min and max values for input variables
---> 22 x_min, x_max = X_test_scaled['synth_index'].min(), X_test_scaled['synth_index'].max()
     23 y_min, y_max = X_test_scaled['ln_GDP_level'].min(), X_test_scaled['ln_GDP_level'].max()
     24 

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I just tried to convert variables with:

```
df['synth_index'].astype(np.int64)
df['ln_GDP_level'].astype(np.int64)
```

but the error persists.

How can I solve it? This is the piece of code that gives me an error (I talked with the author of previous code and there was a piece of the code missing!)

```
X=df[['synth_index','ln_GDP_level']]
y=df['median_rating'].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42,
                                                   test_size=0.30)
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

model1 = LinearRegression()
model2 = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=100, epsilon=1)

# Fit the two models 
lr = model1.fit(X_test_scaled, y_test)
svr = model2.fit(X_test_scaled, y_test)

# ----------- For creating a prediction plane to be used in the visualization -----------
# Set Increments between points in a meshgrid
mesh_size = 1

# Identify min and max values for input variables
x_min, x_max = X_test_scaled['synth_index'].min(), X_test_scaled['synth_index'].max()
y_min, y_max = X_test_scaled['ln_GDP_level'].min(), X_test_scaled['ln_GDP_level'].max()

# Return evenly spaced values based on a range between min and max
xrange = np.arange(x_min, x_max, mesh_size)
yrange = np.arange(y_min, y_max, mesh_size)

# Create a meshgrid
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xrange, yrange)

# ----------- Create a prediction plane  -----------
# Use models to create a prediction plane --- Linear Regression
pred_LR = model1.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
pred_LR = pred_LR.reshape(xx.shape)

# Use models to create a prediction plane --- SVR
pred_svr = model2.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
pred_svr = pred_svr.reshape(xx.shape)
```

Database was read with this code (Pandas):

```
datafile = (r'C:\Users\gpont\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\data\Map\databaseCDP0.csv')

df = pd.read_csv(datafile, skiprows = 0, sep=';')

df

df['median_rating'] = df['median_rating'].astype(float)
print()
  
# let's find out the data type after changing
print(df.dtypes)
  
# print dataframe. 
df
```

Database:

[image]

Database type:

[image]

Comment: Please include the code that is generating the error. Also, provide a sample of `df`.

Comment: I updated the previous message with full code.

@mustafaAydin `X=df['median_rating'].values.reshape(-1,1)`

Comment: @GiovanniPontonio When you do that, `X` is a numpy array, not a pandas dataframe or series anymore; hence the error.

Comment: @mustafaAydin , so how can I solve? I imported numpy library

Comment: Ok, so the error is in:

```datafile = (r'C:\Users\gpont\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\data\Map\databaseCDP0.csv')

df = pd.read_csv(datafile, skiprows = 0, sep=';')

df```

?

Comment: What is your intention with `X["median_rating"]`? What is `X` at that point? Where is the first part of the code, can you share that too? Where does `df` play a role here? In short, we need a [mcve].

Comment: I'm following this guide with my Database (see
[sample](https://towardsdatascience.com/support-vector-regression-svr-one-of-the-most-flexible-yet-robust-prediction-algorithms-4d25fbdaca60) )

Comment: You should know the identity of each variable in your code.  `df` is a common name for a pandas dataframe.  Its columns can be identified/indexed by name.  `X` isn't a frame.  Looks like it works in `fit`, but you don't show how it was created.

Comment: @hpaulj take a look to new code edited on the first question.

Comment: I glanced at the tutorial.  You should be asking that author for clarification. We aren't responsible for bugs, omissions, or confusions in published blogs or articles.

Comment: So in this line `x_min, x_max = X['median_rating'].min(), X['median_rating'].max()` did you try changing `X`s to `df`s? Because `X` is a numpy array that knows of no label/index names but `df` is a pandas dataframe and is known for label-based access, as already mentioned in above comment(s). In short, blog post's code is wrong (and that website also asked me to generate an account to read those lines of badly written codes...)

Comment: `values` extracts an array from a dataframe.  You can't index array columns by 'name'.

Comment: I updated the problem! Please help me

Comment: I tried to clean up your question but I had to guess some things; please review.

Comment: You are still not showing us your data.

Comment: @tripleee I updated with images of data. Thank you!

Comment: Argh, no, please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of scaler.transform is an numpy array, in your case it's a 2-D array, and no longer a pandas dataframe. So you can't access "synth_index" column using "synth_index" as the key.

Use the code below to solve your problem.

```
# Identify min and max values for input variables
x_min, x_max = X_test_scaled[:, 0].min(), X_test_scaled[:, 0].max()
y_min, y_max = X_test_scaled[:, 1].min(), X_test_scaled[:, 1].max()
```